# Node js Passport authorization - JWT Strategy doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am trying to build a meanauth app where I am using jws token to authorize the user.

this is my route/users.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('../config/database');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var Log = require('log')
  , log = new Log('info');

const User = require('../model/users');
//const ap = express();

//Register router
router.post('/register',(req,res,next)=>{
  log.info('entering register');
  let newUser = new User({
    name:req.body.name,
    email:req.body.email,
    username:req.body.username,
    password:req.body.password
  });
  User.addUser(newUser,(err,user)=>{
    log.info("inside add user");
    if(err){
      log.error('error while registaring ' + err);
      res.json({success:false,msg:'failed to register user'});
    }
    else {
      res.json({sucess:true,msg:'user registered succefully'});
    }
  })
});
router.post('/authenticate',(req,res,next)=>{
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  User.getUserByUsername(username,(err,user)=>{
  if(err)
  throw err;
  if(!user)
  {
    return res.json({success:false,msg:'user not found'});
  }
  User.comparePassword(password,user.password,(err,isMatch) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(isMatch){
      const token = jwt.sign(user,config.secret,{
        expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
      });
      res.json({
        success:true,
        token:'JWT'+token,
        id:user._id,
        name:user.name,
        username:user.username,
        email:user.email
      });
    }
    else
      {
        return res.json({success:false,msg:'wrong password'});
      }
  });


});
});
router.get('/profile',passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),(req,res,next)=>{
  log.info('inside profile');
  res.json({user: req.user});
});
module.exports=router;
```

this is passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../model/users');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
  let opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,(jwt_payload,done)=>{
    console.log("inside passport");
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id,(err,user)=>{
      if(err)
      {
        return done(err,false);
      }
      if(user){
        return done(null,user);
      }
      else {
        return done(null,false);
      }
    })
  }));
}
```

when I make request to /profile using the jwt authorization token, I get unauthorized message, I tried to console log inside the /profile route and in passport.js but I am not getting any thing, what is the problem here ?

Comment: i think no problem with code either you have not registered previously(new user) or credentials while logging must be wrong thats why unauthorized......try debugging using consoles inside `post authenticate` and you will know which part of authenticate creates problem.

Comment: @wrangler I am able to authenticate the user with his username and password and I am getting the jwt token also, the problem occurs only when I try to access the profile using jwt access token

Comment: If console.log inside passport.js is not printing that means new user is not created........try creating a new user and then authenticating then share the log file ,could help only after that without log file its quite confusing.

Comment: What does your `Authorization` header look like?